# Delete all disabled modules in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How do I disable an unused module from Jenkins builds? I'm not seeing any option to "Delete All Disabled Modules" in my Jenkins. I am using Jenkins version 2.107.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7172

or can try this

```
    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.class).findAll{job -> job.isBuildable()}.each{
job ->
  job.getDisabledModules(true).each{module -> module.delete()}
  println(job.name+" cleaned")
}
```